# Sequence not working with LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I'm trying to insert data to a table with a sequence to generate an ID automatically. 
**Table and Sequence**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Hotel] (
[HotelId]          VARCHAR (50)    NOT NULL,
[HotalName]         VARCHAR (50)   NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([HotelId] ASC)
);

GO
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.IDSeq AS
INT START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1 ;
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Hotel
ADD CONSTRAINT Const_HotelId_Seq
DEFAULT FORMAT((NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.IDSeq),'HO-0000#') FOR HotelId;
GO
```

I tried to insert data in 2 different ways,

**Method 1 (Working method)**

```
INSERT INTO Hotel([HotelName]) VALUES ('Shangrilla')
```

**Method 2(Not working)**

```
DataClassesDataContext dc = new DataClassesDataContext ();
dc.Hotels.InsertOnSubmit(hotel);
dc.SubmitChanges();
dc.Dispose();
```

Data insertion is not working on code. How may I fix this?

Comment: what version of entity framework?

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: SqlException. Not allowed null values on HotelId Column

Comment: How may I check the EF version?

Comment: Your `HotelId` needs the `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` attribute or something similar let it know not to include it in inserts.

Comment: But it's varchar. Not possible to set DbGenerated. It gives an error

Comment: Can you please post your model and the 'hotel' object code?

Comment: I'm using LINQ. I didn't create an object for it

Comment: @codebot Really, what about using `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed`?

Comment: @codebot Your Linq has to use entities that either you wrote your you had VS create for you.